# Riemann Siegel formula modification?

Tags: prime-numbers, approximation, riemann-zeta

$$Z(t)= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt t/2\pi\rfloor }\frac{\cos(N(t)-t\log p_{n})}{\sqrt n}$$

here $N(t)$  is the smooth part of the zeros and $ p_{n} $ are the primes since $ p_{n} =n\log n $ then $ \log p_{n}=\log n \log\log n $ for big $n$ so the convergence should be pretty similar

but is this approximaiton valid , here the sum over $n$ is made so $ p_{n} \le \lfloor\sqrt t/2\pi\rfloor$

Comment: Did I correctly assume that "$int$" meant the integer part?

Comment: yes intx is integer part (or floor function) of 'x' i did not know how to put it

Comment: You can write `$\lfloor x \rfloor$` for $\lfloor x \rfloor$